# finding residue with $\oint_C \frac{3z^3 + 2}{(z-1)(z^2 + 9)} dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, factoring, mathematical-physics, contour-integration, residue-calculus

I am doing the integral $\oint_C \dfrac{3z^3 + 2}{(z-1)(z^2 + 9)} dz$, and I am trying to find the residue at the pole $3i$;I am unsure how to do this. Could I factor $z^2 + 9$ further?

Comment: Considering the fundamental theorem of algebra, of course you can factor $z^2 + 9$ further. Consider how you would factor $z^2 + 1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pole is simple and so the residue is

$$\begin{align} \lim_{z\rightarrow 3i}(z - 3i) f(z) &  = & \lim_{z\rightarrow 3i} (z - 3i) \frac{3z^3 + 2}{(z - 1)(z^3 + 9)} \\& = & \lim_{z\rightarrow 3i}\frac{3z^3 + 2}{(z - 1)(z + 3i)} \\ & = & \frac{-81i + 2}{(3i - 1)(6i)} \\ & = & \frac{2 - 81i}{18 + 6i} \end{align}$$

Warning:  I just learnt complex analysis in a few hours the other day so I'm not 100% sure myself, answering for my own education too :)

Comment: Doesn't affect the final answer, but you lost the term of $(z-3i)$ in the first equality (although you cancelled it in the second equality so that fixes it).

Answer (score 0):

$(z^2 + 9) = (z+ 3i)(z-3i)$
Try to multiply it out and see what you get :)